# SQL Server 2016 Availability Groups Named Pipes?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, availability-groups, connectivity

We have a SQL Server 2016 cluster configured (two VM's) with our databases spread across multiple Availability Groups (AG).

Our Sharepoint admin is reporting to me that some functionality is failing as it requires Named Pipes. Now, named pipes are enabled but from some very old articles (pre-2013) I can see that Named Pipes were not supported on multiple IP addresses, which would cause issues for the AG listeners.

Can anyone confirm if this is the case? Or point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 6):

From the documentation on [Listeners, Client Connectivity, Application Failover](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/listeners-client-connectivity-application-failover?view=sql-server-2017#AGlisteners)

> An availability group listener consists of a Domain Name System (DNS)
>   listener name, listener port designation, and one or more IP
>   addresses. **Only the TCP protocol is supported by availability group
>   listener**. The DNS name of the listener must also be unique in the
>   domain and in NetBIOS.

So only TCP/IP is supported.